# Hardhat testing a null address if is contract

Tags: contract-development, hardhat, testing, unittesting

I have the following method in my contract:

```
function setup(address _fooAddress) external onlyOwner {
  require(_fooAddress.isContract(), "_fooAddress is not a contract"); 
}
```

And I am trying to test it with hardhat, I am passing `_fooAddress` as `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` but I get the `_fooAddress is not a contract` error.

```
const { setup } = await contract();

await setup("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
```

Any idea why `null address` is not evaluated as a contract address?

Comment: What is you see is what you get. `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` is not a contract in the Hardhat Network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way an isContract() works is that it tests for the size/amount of code at the address being more than 0.
If no code at the address, isContract() returns false. To get it to return true, there must be some code deployed to the address.

There's no code deployed to the zero address